# Linking an SRSS report - Dropdown parameter not getting passed

Tags: drop-down-menu, reporting-services, parameters, linked-list, report

Sorry if this is a duplicate post, not sure what happened with my original one.

I have a linked SSRS report (Report A) that links to Report B. One of Report B's parameters is controlled by a Dropdown/ComboBox. In the parameters dialog box that gets launched from the navigation tab, I have tried both 'VALUE' and simply putting VALUE without the single quotes.

Both ways result in an error stating that the parameter was not provided. How do I correctly pass this value, so that Report B will recognize it?

Thanks

Comment: Just for clarification, the ComboBox appears in Report A or Report B?

Comment: Hi Tin,

The ComboBox appears in Report B. 

Thanks

Comment: Think you did everything correctly, and most likely there was something else at play (making this question quite "localized"), for example 'VALUE' not being a available value.